# Shouldn't insert just be O(n) not O(1) or O(n) inserting into unsorted linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, linked-list, runtime

This falls under "a software algorithm" from stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in this case, a software algorithm to add an item to a unsorted array list.

This is chart we made in class about the runtimes of operations on different data structures 
[image]

The one I want to focus on is inserting a value into a unsorted array list. Here is our code for doing so

```
 public void insert(E value) {
    insertAtIndex(size, value);
}
public void insertAtIndex(int index, E value) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index: " + index);
    }
    if (size == 0) {
        ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>(value);
        front = back = newNode;
    }
    else {

        if (index == 0) {
            ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>(value, front);
            front = newNode;
        }
        else {
            ListNode<E> current = nodeAt(index - 1);
            ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>(value, current.next);
            current.next = newNode;
            if (index == size) {
                back = newNode;
            }
        }       

    }
    size++;
}
 private ListNode<E> nodeAt(int index) {
    ListNode<E> current = front;
    for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
            current = current.next;
    }
    return current;
}
```

When you do runtime analysis on the insert method, isn't it just O(n), not O(1) or O(n)? I get how the insert method could run in O(1). If size == 0, you just do one two quick operations, creating the new node, and assigning it to front.

However in terms of the runtime analysis, https://academics.tjhsst.edu/compsci/CS2C/U2/bigoh.html, when you evaluate if else if branch of insert at index, shouldn't you "assume the worst case and and thus the running time of the if/else will be the sum of the running time of the test and the running time of the worst-case statement". If you do it that way, you see the worst case run time is in the else branch because it involves the nodeAt method which runs in O(n).

Because of this won't the whole insertAtIndex and insert methods run in O(n), not O(1)? From what I see in the chart, O(1) would be interpreted as a correct possibility. But from that analysis, O(n) should be the only possibility.

Comment: Actually if you wanna to put it this way then nodeAt(2) is O(2) .. nodeAt(3) is O(3) ..and so on.  You're thinking too much. As programmers we try to avoid thinking as much as possible.

Comment: You could keep a pointer to the last element of your list. This avoids your call to `nodeAt(index - 1)` and immediately inserts the new element at the end.

Comment: @homeless this implementation doesn't have a back pointer the column two the right does.

Comment: @Qwertyzw such a hard line to define though. Isn't the point of this class, data structures and algorithms, to make you think about runtime, data structures, the best way to do something, etc....

Comment: The algorithm you pictured runs in O(n) and not O(1) as it needs every time to go through all the elements of the list.

Comment: I see you are posting a few algorithm related questions. If you want to get deeper responses then cs.stackexchange is better.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you further:  http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: @homeless That's what I am saying. It should be just O(n), not O(n) or O(1)

Comment: By "array list" I think you mean "linked list". There's no arrays in your implementation.

Comment: @committedandroider Maybe I am missing a point, but your understanding is in my opinion right. However, it depends on your teacher/professor's definition in class. The pictured algorithm is definitely O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your insert code runs in O(n). To run in O(1) it should insert at index 0 rather than at the end of the list.

In general, the statement that something can be done in O(f) is not a statement that every implementation is O(f) but rather than an optimal implementation is O(f).

The second confusion that you have is about the entries "O(1) or O(n)" in the table. They correspond to the linked list being unsorted (so an insert can insert at index 0) or sorted (so an insert has to find the correct insertion point).

Comment: yeah how did i miss the unsorted vs sorted part...... So focused on the details but missed the big picture